# i am getting an error while working with esp8266

Tags: esp8266

i got an error
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
An error occurred while uploading the sketch

can [esp8266](http://uitechies.co.in/BBBcircuits/product.php?product=serial-wi-fi-wireless-transceiver-module-iot-esp8266)anyone rectify this

Comment: disconnect the esp8266 from RX/TX. it disturbs the upload

Answer (score 0):

oh i got the solution for the above question

it might be because i used TX AND RX pins of the arduino. what i observed is as tx and rx pins are for serial communication pin during the process of uploading i have to leave that pins disconnected.[arduino](http://uitechies.co.in/BBBcircuits/product.php?product=arduino-uno-r3-atmega328p)